# Order by custom meta value (int) confusion

Tags: wordpress

I have the follow args:

```
array(7) {
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(6) "website"
  ["posts_per_page"]=>
  string(3) "150"
  ["meta_key"]=>
  string(11) "website_rank"
  ["order"]=>
  string(3) "ASC"
  ["orderby"]=>
  string(14) "meta_value_num"
  ["meta_value"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["meta_compare"]=>
  string(1) ">"
}
```

Rather than returning posts with meta_values of 7, 8, 9 ... 150 (desired) they return as 7, 8, 9, 60, 61 ...

I've tried casting as (int) rather than a string but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing 'type' from my meta query. Having used ACF this has never been necessary, but appears that when querying by a post with meta set by update_post_meta() 'type' needs to be used.

In my case

```
'type' => 'NUMERIC'
```

Resolved my issue.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query